# vscode and edge has different mouse cursor size with system

Tags: arch-linux, visual-studio-code

I'm on manjaro with xfce. my mouse cursor size differs when it is on vscode and not. it also happens on edge.

The vscode is installed use aur of `visual-studio-code-bin` package.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what's the issue with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar [issue](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/11671) with MPV;
It looks like they (application & compositor) both need to support **cursor-shape-v1** feature...

Comment: the issue says to use `XCURSOR_SIZE` as a work around, how should I do it??

Comment: Thanks, I added `export XCURSOR_SIZE=16` in `~/.profile`, it fixed